# KMeans With $K = N / 2$

Tags: clustering, k-means, matching

I have two data sets of the same data coming from two different sources. I am trying to match all of the rows in one data set with the other by comparing several columns in each set. Each data set can have errors, so not all points will match.

Currently I am using KMeans by setting the centroids equal to the first data set. Then I am matching each point in the second set by finding the nearest centroid for each point.

So technically I am using KMeans with $K = N / 2$. The data sets contain about 4000 rows, so I have roughly $K = 2000$.

This method is about 80% accurate in finding the exact match, but I would like to improve that. From what I have read, it seems that KMeans wasn't intended to have small clusters with a large numbers of centroids. I don't quite understand why this is. Is it considered bad practice to use Kmeans like this? If so, can someone explain why?

Also, are there any better methods or algorithms more suitable for my problem?

Comment: Why not find the exact matches and remove them before resorting to approximations?

Comment: I tried taking out the exact matches and the result was about the same  $\pm 5\%$. There are not many "exact matches" and it is difficult to set a threshold for the minimum distance to determine if the data points are actually a match.

Comment: Your task is not 100% clear to me. Note that if you have two sets 1 and 2 of sizes espectively n1<=n2, and you want to match all points in the 1st set with n1 most similar points with the 2nd set, so that the overall summed similarity across matched pairs is maximal, the optimal solution is given by Hungarian algorithm. You will first have to compute similarity/distance between points of the two sets.